# Mongoose multiple search query parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I've implemented a search box in a table but now I need to search multiple fields and not just `schoolName`

The code I have so far is the following

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    User.find({ schoolName: regex }, function(err, users) {
      res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        total: users.length,
        users: users
      });
    });
  } else {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
      res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        total: users.length,
        users: users
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I want to be able to search by `schoolName`, `city`, `schoolRepresentativeName` and `schoolRepresentativeTutorMentor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query to achieve the desired result.

```
User.find({
    $or: [
        {schoolName: regex},
        {city: regex},
        {schoolRepresentativeName: regex},
        {schoolRepresentativeTutorMentor: regex}
    ]
}, function (err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        total: users.length,
        users: users
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**I believe escapeRegex() is create the regex for the string.**

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
let query = req.query;
let orquery = [];

for (const key in query) {
    orquery.push({
        key: new RegExp(escapeRegex(query[key]), 'gi')
    });
}
User.find({
    $or: orquery
}, function (err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        total: users.length,
        users: users
    });
});
```

});